# Is there an equivalent/replacement of System.Window.Media.Model3DGroup class in UWP?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, uwp-xaml

Is there an equivalent/replacement of System.Window.Media.Model3DGroup class in UWP? Searched all over and can't find any.

This is the sample WPF code I want to replicate in UWP:

```
        <Model3DGroup.Children>

          <!-- Group Child 0 -->

          <Model3DGroup >
            <Model3DGroup.Transform>
              <Transform3DGroup>
                <Transform3DGroup.Children>
                  <Transform3DCollection >
                    <ScaleTransform3D ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"  ScaleZ="1" />
                    <RotateTransform3D >
                      <RotateTransform3D.Rotation >
                        <AxisAngleRotation3D x:Name="myRotate" Axis="1 0 0" Angle="0" />
                      </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                    </RotateTransform3D>
                    <TranslateTransform3D OffsetX="0" OffsetY="0" OffsetZ="0" />
                  </Transform3DCollection>
                </Transform3DGroup.Children>
              </Transform3DGroup>
            </Model3DGroup.Transform>

            <Model3DGroup.Children>

                                <!-- Child 0 -->
                                <!-- BACK -->
                                <GeometryModel3D  Transform="{StaticResource CubeMeshTransform2}">
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                        <MeshGeometry3D

                                        TriangleIndices="       0,1,2 
                                                                3,4,5 "
                                        TextureCoordinates="    1,0     1,1     0,1 
                                                                0,1     0,0     1,0"
                                        Positions="-0.5,-0.5,-0.5   -0.5,0.5,-0.5   0.5,0.5,-0.5    
                                                    0.5,0.5,-0.5    0.5,-0.5,-0.5   -0.5,-0.5,-0.5  
                                                                        "
                                    />
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                        <DiffuseMaterial>
                                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                                <VisualBrush>
                                                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                                        <MediaElement Name="media0" IsMuted="True"  LoadedBehavior="Manual" MediaEnded="RestartMedia">

                                                        </MediaElement>
                                                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                                                </VisualBrush>
                                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                </GeometryModel3D>
                                <!-- Front -->
                                <GeometryModel3D  Transform="{StaticResource CubeMeshTransform2}">
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                        <MeshGeometry3D

                                        TextureCoordinates="0,1 1,1 1,0
                                            1,0 0,0 0,1
                                                            "
                                        Positions="-0.5,-0.5,0.5     0.5,-0.5,0.5   0.5,0.5,0.5 
                                                    0.5,0.5,0.5     -0.5,0.5,0.5    -0.5,-0.5,0.5  
                                                                        "
                                    />
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                        <DiffuseMaterial>
                                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                                <VisualBrush>
                                                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                                        <MediaElement Name="media3"  IsMuted="True"  LoadedBehavior="Manual" MediaEnded="RestartMedia">
                                                        </MediaElement>
                                                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                                                </VisualBrush>
                                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                </GeometryModel3D>
                                <!-- Bottom -->
                                <GeometryModel3D  Transform="{StaticResource CubeMeshTransform2}">
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                        <MeshGeometry3D

                                        TextureCoordinates="1,1 0,1 0,0 0,0 1,0 1,1  "
                                        Positions="-0.5,-0.5,-0.5 0.5,-0.5,-0.5 0.5,-0.5,0.5 0.5,-0.5,0.5 -0.5,-0.5,0.5 -0.5,-0.5,-0.5 
                                                                        "
                                    />
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                        <DiffuseMaterial>
                                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                                <VisualBrush>
                                                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                                        <MediaElement  IsMuted="True"  LoadedBehavior="Manual" MediaEnded="RestartMedia" Name="media4">
                                                        </MediaElement>
                                                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                                                </VisualBrush>
                                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                </GeometryModel3D>
                                <!-- Right -->
                                <GeometryModel3D  Transform="{StaticResource CubeMeshTransform2}">
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                        <MeshGeometry3D

                                        TextureCoordinates="0,1 0,0 1,0 1,0 1,1 0,1"
                                        Positions=" 0.5,-0.5,-0.5 0.5,0.5,-0.5 0.5,0.5,0.5 0.5,0.5,0.5 0.5,-0.5,0.5 0.5,-0.5,-0.5
                                                                        "
                                    />
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                        <DiffuseMaterial>
                                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                                <VisualBrush>
                                                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                                        <MediaElement  IsMuted="True" Name="media5" LoadedBehavior="Manual" MediaEnded="RestartMedia">    
                                                            </MediaElement>
                                                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                                                </VisualBrush>
                                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                </GeometryModel3D>
                                <!-- Top -->
                                <GeometryModel3D  Transform="{StaticResource CubeMeshTransform2}">
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                        <MeshGeometry3D

                                        TextureCoordinates=" 0,0 1,0 1,1 1,1 0,1 0,0"
                                        Positions=" 0.5,0.5,-0.5 -0.5,0.5,-0.5 -0.5,0.5,0.5 -0.5,0.5,0.5 0.5,0.5,0.5 0.5,0.5,-0.5 
                                                                        "
                                    />
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                        <DiffuseMaterial>
                                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                                <VisualBrush>
                                                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                                        <MediaElement  IsMuted="True" Name="media6" LoadedBehavior="Manual" MediaEnded="RestartMedia">

                                                        </MediaElement>
                                                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                                                </VisualBrush>
                                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                </GeometryModel3D>
                                <!-- left -->
                                <GeometryModel3D  Transform="{StaticResource CubeMeshTransform2}">
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                        <MeshGeometry3D
        TextureCoordinates="1,0 1,1 0,1  0,1 0,0 1,0 "
        Positions="-0.5,0.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.5,0.5 -0.5,-0.5,0.5 -0.5,0.5,0.5 -0.5,0.5,-0.5 " />
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                        <DiffuseMaterial>
                                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                                <VisualBrush>
                                                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                                        <MediaElement  IsMuted="True" Name="media2" LoadedBehavior="Manual" MediaEnded="RestartMedia">

                                                        </MediaElement>
                                                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                                                </VisualBrush>
                                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                </GeometryModel3D>
                            </Model3DGroup.Children>
          </Model3DGroup>


          <Model3DGroup>
            <Model3DGroup.Children>
              <AmbientLight Color="#ffcccccc"/>
              <DirectionalLight Color="LightGray" Direction="-1,-1,-1" />
            </Model3DGroup.Children>
          </Model3DGroup>
        </Model3DGroup.Children>
```

Key thing to note is that there are 6 Media element controls()  representing each side of the cube.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot simply say which class in uwp is equivalent/replacement the [`System.Window.Media.Model3DGroup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.model3dgroup(v=vs.110).aspx) class in wpf. `Model3DGroup` in wpf is for using a number of 3-D models as a unit. Since one [`ModelVisual3D`](http://ModelVisual3D) can only have one [`Model3D`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.model3d(v=vs.110).aspx), we can compose Model3D objects by using a `Model3DGroup` to form a single model and set it as the content of `ModelVisual3D` element.

But in uwp, `Modelvisual3D`,`Model3D`, and even the `Viewport3D` are all not supported. So we don't need the `Mode3DGroup` class.

Actually which class should use in your app is depended on your requirements. E.g. What features you want to implement. For example, a simple demo about `Rectangle` rotation in wpf which contains the `Model3DGroup` as follows:

```
<Viewport3D Name="myViewport">
    <Viewport3D.Camera>
                <PerspectiveCamera
                    FarPlaneDistance="20"
                    FieldOfView="45"
                    LookDirection="5,-2,-3"
                    NearPlaneDistance="0"
                    Position="-5,2,3"
                    UpDirection="0,1,0" />
            </Viewport3D.Camera>
    <ModelVisual3D x:Name="topModelVisual3D">
        <ModelVisual3D.Children>
            <ModelVisual3D x:Name="children1">
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <Model3DGroup>                           
                        <GeometryModel3D Geometry="{StaticResource myTeapot}">
                            <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                <DiffuseMaterial>
                                    <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Opacity="1.0" Color="Pink" />
                                    </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                </DiffuseMaterial>
                            </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                            <GeometryModel3D.Transform>
                                        <RotateTransform3D>
                                            <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                                <AxisAngleRotation3D
                                                x:Name="myAngleRotation"
                                                Angle="1"
                                                Axis="0,3,0" />
                                            </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                        </RotateTransform3D>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Transform>
                        </GeometryModel3D>
                    </Model3DGroup>
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
        </ModelVisual3D.Children>
    </ModelVisual3D>
    <Viewport3D.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Viewport3D.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Duration="0:0:10"
                        From="0"
                        RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="myAngleRotation"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                        To="360" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Viewport3D.Triggers>
</Viewport3D>
```

And we can have similar effects on uwp by following code.

```
<Grid x:Name="ImageGrid" Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid.Projection>
        <PlaneProjection />
    </Grid.Projection> 
    <Rectangle
        x:Name="ImageBlock"
        Width="100"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Fill="Black"          
        Stretch="Uniform" Height="100">
        <Rectangle.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Name="SpinAnimation">
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Duration="0:0:5"
                            From="360"
                            RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="ImageGrid"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)"
                            To="0" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Rectangle.Triggers>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

I think the guides you need are [Draw shapes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/graphics/drawing-shapes) and [Animation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/graphics/animations-overview) in uwp. For complex 3D Graphics please reference [Direct3D](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476080(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I'm asking if there is a way to get multiple 3D objects to appear as one(like a cube, for example) in UWP?

Comment: @user111 what  `multiple 3D objects ` you mean here in uwp? A cube it is one 3D object, right? uwp doesn't have object like `GeometryModel3D`, could you please detail your requirements? E.g. give a example uwp xaml page with `mutiple 3D objects` show.

Comment: So in the  WPF example I am trying to replicate,a cube is 6 different GeometryModel3D objects representing the 6 respective sides of the cube. 

I edited my question with more detailed requirements